# How to create a search using PHP, mysqli and a html form

Tags: php, search

I want to create a form which allows the user to type in a search and have it pick up the right values from a database and display them, for some reason I can't get my query to work it just displays "could not search"

Here is my php code

```html
 <?php

  include "connect.php";

  $output = '';

  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);

    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM house WHERE town LIKE '%$search%'") or die ("Could not search");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
    if($count == 0){
      $output = "There was no search results!";

    }else{

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $town = $row ['town'];
        $street = $row ['street'];
        $bedrooms = $row ['bedrooms'];
        $bathroom = $row ['bathrooms'];

        $output .='<div> '.$town.''.$street.''.$bedrooms.''.$bathrooms.'</div>';

      }

    }
  }

  ?>
```

Here is my form

```html
 <form action ="home.php" method = "post">
  
          <input name="search" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Belfast"/>

          <input type="submit" value="Search"/>

          </form> 

          <?php print ("$output");?>
```

Comment: replace `'%$search%'` with `'%".$search."%'`...

Comment: didn't work, still says 'Could not search!'

Comment: `echo` your query `SELECT * FROM house WHERE town LIKE '%$search%'` and try the query from phpmyadmin or mysql...

Comment: This might help. http://askseeker.com/code-snippets/search-form-php-using-mysqli/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not connecting to your DB in your query:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT
                      ^ missing connection variable
```

there is no connection variable (unknown what you are using to connect with)

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ...
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Object oriented style
`mixed mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

Procedural style
`mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

figuring you are using `mysqli_` to connect with. If you're using `mysql_` or PDO to connect with, that won't work. Those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.

Plus, instead of `or die ("Could not search")` do `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to catch any errors, if any.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Example `mysqli` connection:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 
                or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
```

For more information, visit:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Can you please explain it for my knowledge? `Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.`

Comment: @Testing Should there be any errors that will display system paths, db tables/column names the person does not want to show, connection credentials, those should not be displayed to the user.

Comment: I have a connection to the database in a connect file which I already have included

Comment: @Rebekah You still need to pass the connection variable to your query. I don't know which variable you're using to connect with, which is why I used `$connection` as an example. You will have to replace it with the one you're using.

Comment: Just change your query to `$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM house WHERE town LIKE '%$search%'") or die ("Could not search");` - Here I used `$con`, seeing that's what you're using as a variable in your other question. You need to pass the connection to your query, just reload my answer also. @Rebekah

Comment: @Rebekah You're welcome. Please mark it as solved then.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM house WHERE town LIKE '%$search%'") or die ("Could not search");

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

The `$connection` is the variable declared in your connect.php to connect to your database .

You should have out the `$result` before the `$count`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the space between `if($count==0)`  it will start working!!

```
if($count==0){
      $output = "There was no search results!";}
```

Comment: Despite the fact that this might be solved or not of relevance after **four years** spaces in this context have to effect.